# Cygwin+Mintty password prompt problems

Tags: windows, cygwin, mintty

The latest version of Cygwin doesn't use the windows command prompt by default, but Mintty instead. Initially, I loved mintty because it is much more reponsive and pastes on middle click. However, there is a big problem with this setup:

Any password prompts are not displayed. This is true for `git`, `psql` and others. This means that when I run the program and a `Password:` prompt should appear, nothing happens instead. It doesn't help to just enter the password either, then still nothing happens.

I know it's an issue with Mintty and/or Cygwin, because I also have the "git bash" installed that comes with the default Windows Git installation, and it works there.

System description: Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit, Cygwin (pretty late version) (How do you find out the cygwin version?), mintty 1.1.2, zsh (but it's the same problem in bash).

How can I get cygwin+mintty to display my password prompts?

Or can I get Cygwin to use the windows command shell again (which I hate, but it's better than not displaying command prompts)?

Answer (score 1):

Thought there is two ways

1. Try alternative consoles? [ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) or [Console2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/440370/1405560) for example.
2. Run `sh.exe --login -i` instead of mintty. I believe `sh.exe` exists in the same folder as `mintty.exe`, because mintty is not a shell but terminal only.